# Cannot resolve symbol generated AutoValue_Foo class inside pure java module in android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, auto-value

I am trying to use AutoValue in a module that is written in pure Java that acts the domain module for my Android application. My application is composed of 3 layers, presentation, domain and data. Presentation and Data both have android dependencies, but domain does not.

Here is the AutoValue class data implementation :

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import java.util.Date;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Trip {
public abstract int id();
public abstract String name();
public abstract int totalDistance();
@Nullable public abstract Date startDate();
@Nullable public abstract Date endDate();

public static Builder builder() {
    return new AutoValue_Trip.Builder().totalDistance(0);
}

@AutoValue.Builder
public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder id(int id);
        public abstract Builder name(String name);
        public abstract Builder totalDistance(int totalDistance);
        public abstract Builder startDate(Date startDate);
        public abstract Builder endDate(Date endDate);
        public abstract Trip build();
    }
}
```

**Android Studio cannot find the generated AutoValue_Trip class**, so it marks it as an error **however, the project builds and runs just fine.**

Here is my build.gradle of the domain module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.12"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    def domainDependencies = rootProject.ext.domainDependencies
    def domainTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.domainTestDependencies

    apt domainDependencies.autoValue
    compileOnly domainDependencies.autoValue

    provided domainDependencies.javaxAnnotation

    compile domainDependencies.javaxInject
    compile domainDependencies.rxJava
    compile domainDependencies.arrow

    testCompile domainTestDependencies.junit
    testCompile domainTestDependencies.mockito
    testCompile domainTestDependencies.assertj
}
```

I have tried using a sourceSet as follows to add the generated build files and folders to the source path:

```
main {
    java {
        srcDirs += 'src/../build/generated'
    }
}
```

But then I was getting compileJava errors.

Has anyone ran into this issue and how did you correct it? Additional info will be provided if necessary.